# Table sorter not working as expected after moving code between pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

It used to work and I was moving it from one webpage to another (I have also copied the CSS and JS list as the old webpage) and then it does not work.

```
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}assets/css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}assets/js/tablesorter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}assets/js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

                <table id="keywords" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><span>Serial Number</span></th>
                            <th><span>Name</span></th>
                            <th><span>Model</span></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                            {% for measurement in measurement_list %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="lalign">{{ measurement.set.machine.sn }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ measurement.set.name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ measurement.set.model }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ measurement.user }}</td>
                                </tr>
                            {% endfor %} 


                    </tbody>
                </table>

</body>
```

In Javascript i have also included `tablesorter.js` in my heading, and this function is wrapped by `$(document).ready(function)`:

```
$(function() {
    $('#keywords').tablesorter();
});
```

the CSS/JS links all worked and I have exact same code(in the table div) as the origin page. I don't know why it does not work.

Comment: Check the console for errors. You must have missed something if it worked before and doesn't now. Are the paths all correct?

Comment: Yes they are all correct. I checked F12 console, there's only a small css problem. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Just to be sure, can you replace you tablesorter.js src by this https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/tablesorter/2.17.4/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js ?

Comment: I tried, it does not work either. @UgoT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's due to some div problems in the new page which don't fit the old JS file (in which I call  `$('#keywords').tablesorter();`).

I move the function to a separate JS file and then link back to the html, then it works.